# How can I correctly import this structure from a file?

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to write a programme to solve the knapsack problem in C. As part of this assignment, we have been asked to open a text file which has the contents as follows, read the objects, weights, value and cost of each object from the file. I just have no idea how I would go about importing this information and storing it in the correct order in terms of a structure.
Heres an example of the format in which the text files are presented is objects.txt:

> Blockquote

Value   Weight  Cost

7   1       4

6   5       10

6   11      15

5   4       8

4   2       20

3   6       8

2   4       9

2   10      3

1   6       7

Comment: Sorry, we can not do your assignment. Please try to do it by yourself and if you face any issues then ask the question.

Comment: This isnt doing my assignment, if you read the whole question you would see this is the only element of it which i cant figure out.

Comment: I would suggest to add your code along with the question asked.

Comment: Did you even try to [gxxgle this](https://www.google.ch/search?q=reading+data+from+a+text+file+into+a+struct+in+c)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is Sunday, and your assignment is probably due tomorrow... We don't do homework, but we can give some guidelines.

To read data from a text file you open it with `FILE *fp=fopen(...`. After opening the file (and checking it has succesfully been opened), you can read lines in two ways:

- by calling `fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d ",...` and checking the number of arguments you want have been read (and if not, you are probably at end-of-file), or
- by calling `fgets` to read a line into a buffer, and then processing the buffer, for which you can use `sscanf` much like `fscanf`.

Note: you do this in a loop until `fscanf` or `fgets` cannot read anything anymore. You *do not* loop `while (!feof(fp))` because `feof` reports there is nothing more to read *after* a read failed.

You read the data into the members of the structure. I assume you have an array of structures and I assume the array is large enough to hold all data (dynamic allocation will be later on in your course).

Finally you close the file with `fclose`.

Comment: Will this store it in the structure in accordance to weight, price, value etc? i know how to read things in its just I dont know how when reading in the file to differentiate the figures between their sub categories

Comment: No, it will not, Sorting the data is up to you.